# Is it possible to place a character on a border line displayed in a table?

Tags: html

Is it possible to place a character *on* a border line displayed in a table?

I am trying to discover a way to re-create musical staff notation for webpages using html rather than inserting images.

I have actually got the staff itself to render fine, 5 horizontal lines divided by vertical bars using this in my css header:

```
table.musStaff{border-collapse:collapse;}
.trms{border-bottom:2px solid black;}
.tdms{border-left:2px solid black;}
```

and this where I need to render a musical staff:

```
<table class="musStaff">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="trms"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="trms"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="trms"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="trms"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="trms"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td class="tdms">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

All the `&nbsp;` are merely included as temporary place holders.

So my problem is I need to be able to place `&#9679` chars representing notes *on* the lines as well as between the lines, rendered by the `<tr class="trms">` (`border-bottom:2px solid black`).

Other than that I think I would be good to go.

Comment: You can just use `position: relative; top: x px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

HTML

```
<div><span>o</span></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 1em;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7epvLLm/)

Answer (score 2):

You can position anything anywhere you like if you are willing to get into the details and cross-browser issues of css positioning.

For example:

```
<td style="position:relative; top:-12px">&#9679</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/markm/2ft3ojbn/

If I were working on this, however, I would seriously look at using svg or the canvas instead of html and css — this is the kind of task these tools are made for. In the end it will be much more maintainable and readable. It will also be easier to program. In fact there are some libraries out there already to help — for example:
http://www.vexflow.com